# List of colors while clicking on button

Tags: xamarin.forms, c#-3.0

I am new to the Xamarin forms and I have designed a button my TL asked me, that when we click a button I want to list colors that are to display a color list.I don't know what to do please help someone.

Comment: https://github.com/vpapenko/ColorPicker

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your specific needs are, but you can refer to document [Listing Colors with BoxView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/boxview#listing-colors-with-boxview) which uses `BoxView` to achieve this.

The `BoxView` is convenient for displaying colors. This program uses a `ListView` to list all the public static read-only fields of the Xamarin.Forms Color structure:

You can refer to the following code:

```
public class NamedColor
{
    // Instance members.
    private NamedColor()
    {
    }

    public string Name { private set; get; }

    public string FriendlyName { private set; get; }

    public Color Color { private set; get; }

    public string RgbDisplay { private set; get; }

    // Static members.
    static NamedColor()
    {
        List<NamedColor> all = new List<NamedColor>();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through the public static fields of the Color structure.
        foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in typeof(Color).GetRuntimeFields ())
        {
            if (fieldInfo.IsPublic &&
                fieldInfo.IsStatic &&
                fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof (Color))
            {
                // Convert the name to a friendly name.
                string name = fieldInfo.Name;
                stringBuilder.Clear();
                int index = 0;

                foreach (char ch in name)
                {
                    if (index != 0 && Char.IsUpper(ch))
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(' ');
                    }
                    stringBuilder.Append(ch);
                    index++;
                }

                // Instantiate a NamedColor object.
                Color color = (Color)fieldInfo.GetValue(null);

                NamedColor namedColor = new NamedColor
                {
                    Name = name,
                    FriendlyName = stringBuilder.ToString(),
                    Color = color,
                    RgbDisplay = String.Format("{0:X2}-{1:X2}-{2:X2}",
                                               (int)(255 * color.R),
                                               (int)(255 * color.G),
                                               (int)(255 * color.B))
                };

                // Add it to the collection.
                all.Add(namedColor);
            }
        }
        all.TrimExcess();
        All = all;
    }

    public static IList<NamedColor> All { private set; get; }
}
```

For more information, you can check the full sample here: [ListViewColors](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/BoxView/ListViewColors):